# Call click handlers after click handler with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button

```
<input type="button" id="myButton"/>
```

with many click events

```
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){ console.log("do something 1")} );
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){ console.log("do something 2")} );
$(document).on("click","#mybutton" function(){ console.log("do something 3")} );
```

I need new click event handling before other click event, and other events handle after success ajax.

```
 $(document).on("click","#mybutton" function(){ 
     pauseOtherClickEvents();
     $ajax(success:{continueOtherClickEvents()});
 } );
```

Is possible solution in jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: Take the functions out of the handlers, and give them names. Now you can call them whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
var benable = true;

$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){ if(benable) {console.log("do something 1")} } );
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){ if(benable) {console.log("do something 2")} } );
$(document).on("click","#mybutton" function(){ if(benable) {console.log("do something 3")} } );


 $(document).on("click","#mybutton" function(){ 
     benable = false;
     $ajax(success:{ benable = true});
 } );
```